# Find duplicate birthday (Java)

Tags: java, birthday-paradox

The code is to run simulations to find out the probability of n people sharing the same birthday.

I compared randomly assigned birthdates to an array of dates. For any dates that has more than 1 equal value, I added one to the numerator.

However, the answer comes out wrong for the code. I am not sure why.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class birthday {
public static void main (String[] args) {

Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("How many trials");
int n = inp.nextInt();

//variable declaration
double[] birthdate = new double[n];
int num = 0;
int numerator = 0;
double bday = 0;
int trials = 0;

//assign birthdays to n people
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    birthdate[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 365) + 1;
    System.out.println(birthdate[i]);
}

for (int i = 1; i <= 365; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        bday = birthdate[j];

        //compare birthdates to dates
        if (bday == i)
            {
                num++;
                if (num > 1)
                {
                    numerator++;
                }
            }
    }
    num = 0;
}

double ans = (double) numerator / n;
System.out.println("The answer is " + ans);

}
}
```

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for letting us know that you wrote that program.

Comment: What is your actual question? What problem are you having with your code?

Comment: The answer of the probability comes out wrong.
For 23 people, it is supposed to be 0.50, but the code gets around 0.04

Comment: Why are you modeling the birthdays as `double`s and not `int`s? (`double[] birthdate` vs `int[] birthdate`)

Comment: this does not measure probability, it looks at one given output for one given random set of dates.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem

Answer (score 1):

> For any dates that has more than 1 equal value, I added one to the numerator.

That's not what your code does. For any date with at least 2 persons having birthday at that date you add the number of those people minus 1 to the numerator.

If you want your code to work according to the above statement, you have to change the following code

```
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
{
    bday = birthdate[j];

    //compare birthdates to dates
    if (bday == i)
        {
            num++;
            if (num > 1)
            {
                numerator++;
            }
        }
}
num = 0;
```

to this code:

```
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
{
    bday = birthdate[j];

    //compare birthdates to dates
    if (bday == i)
        {
            num++;
        }
}
if (num > 1)
{
    numerator++;
}
num = 0;
```

This way the code `if (num > 1) numerator++` isn't repeated for every person (starting from the second one), but done just once per date.

Anyway, I doubt that either version of the code calculates you the "probability of n people sharing the same birthday". If that's what you want to approximate, you should repeat the whole experiment a lot of times, count, in how many of those cases n people were sharing their birthday, and divide it by the number of experiments:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class birthday {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("How many trials?");
        int numExperiments = inp.nextInt();

        System.out.println("How many persons?");
        int n = inp.nextInt();

        // variable declaration
        int dups = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < numExperiments; k++) {
            boolean foundDup = false;
            int[] birthdate = new int[n];

            // assign birthdays to n people
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                birthdate[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 365) + 1;
            }

            // check, if there is a duplicate
            for (int i = 1; i <= 365; i++) {
                int num = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                    // compare birthdates to dates
                    if (birthdate[j] == i) {
                        num++;
                    }
                }
                if (num > 1) {
                    foundDup = true;
                }
                num = 0;
            }

            // count cases with duplicates
            if (foundDup) {
                dups++;
            }
        }

        double ans = (double) dups / numExperiments;
        System.out.println("The answer is " + ans);
    }
}
```

Comment: The suggested improvement will yield a consistent probability of `0` (instead of ~`0.5`) with input `23`.

Comment: @MickMnemonic See last paragraph.

Comment: @MickMnemonic Not before. Now I did. Why?

Comment: @MickMnemonic Just provided full, working code - in case that helps to resolve your doubts.

Comment: Yes, this is much better, as your original version did not really answer the question. Upvoted.

Comment: You could also break out of the outer loop after `foundDup = true;` to make the code a bit more efficient with very large data sets.